# Bought this mint pot from Jewel osco 3 days ago. Browning on leaves and stem now

Tags: plant-care, herbs, mint

[image: mint in a pot]
I bought this pot 3 days ago. It receives sunlight everyday the whole morning. I water it morning and afternoon depending how dry the soil is. It is still dying slowly. I cut 1/3 of the mint from the top as advised by others. However some stems are browning more and it looks more withered as time passes. 
Please help me and my plant. First time so I don't wanna lose it

Answer (score 1):

I think you are giving it too much water and not enough light.  Try watering once a week and putting it right by the window.  The top half inch of the soil should be dry before watering again